# Find specific file with a for loop

Tags: bash

I have a list of files in multiple directories. I would like to work on specific files but the naming is a little tricky.

```
file_986.aln
file_99.aa.aln
file_99.aln
file_991.aa.aln
file_991.aln
```

I would like to get hold of

```
file_986.aln
 file_99.aln
 file_991.aln
```

only.

How do I modify this command to only pick the `.aln` and not `.aa.aln`?

```
for file in ~/files/100/98/*/file_*.aln; do echo $file; done
```

Comment: please explain the down vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
for file in `ls ~/files/100/98/*/file_*.aln|egrep -v "aa.aln"`; do echo $file; done
```

Should work

Comment: That's not a really pretty workaround, and it will break on file names with spaces or special characters. Please read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Thank you for the wiki reference! the files do not have special characters and spaces. But it is important to be aware of that gotcha.